# vNext Dependency Injection Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have created an ASP.Net vNext Web API.

I have successfully used the dependency inection with a simple interface such as this:

```
services.AddScoped<ILinearRegressionCalculator, LinearRegressionCalculator>();
```

However, I can't figure out how to do dependency inection with a Generic Interface.

How do I setup dependency injection for this interface:

```
public interface IMongoConnectionHandler<T> where T : IMongoEntity
```

Comment: open generics, good question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following is an example:

`services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptions<>), typeof(OptionsManager<>)));`

Source: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23